# Insert into room using list vs for loop In Android

Tags: android, database, performance, memory, android-room

What is best for memory and performance !
I have some data came from fire base through a listener, should i put them on a list of object using for loop then insert the list to the room or make a for loop and looping the (insert to room) !!!

Method 1 :

```
List<object> list = new List<>. 
();
For (int i;i>= list.size; i++){
list.add(data);
}
InsertToRoom(list);
```

Method 2:

```
For (int i;i>= list.size; i++){
InsertToRoom(name, age)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use **only Method 1**.
Because inside "Method 1" you are calling the expensive databse operation `InsertToRoom()` **only once.**

Whereas, inside "Method 2" you are calling the expensive database operations multiple times, i.e. the `InsertToRoom()` operation will be called multiple times until the for loop gets completed. This is not performant and efficient.

As a *Good Android Citizen* you should restrict multiple calls to database, unless genuinely required.

Hence, please go with **Method 1**.

Comment: I agree, my only thought is i am gonna create a list maybe not just one for that operation which will definitely affect the memory !